# Why does my Custom QML Tooltip have no background?

Tags: qt, qml, pyside6

I have created a custom tooltip style using this guide: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#creating-a-custom-style

here is `ToolTip.qml` within my style:

```
import QtQuick.Templates 2.0 as T
import QtQuick

T.ToolTip {
    id: ctrl
    contentItem: Text{
        color: "red"
        text: ctrl.text
    }
    background: Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        border.color: "yellow"
    }
}
```

And here is how I use it:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQml 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 2.15
import QtQuick

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visibility: Window.Maximized

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        id: button
        text: "Click me"
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Clicked")
        }
        ToolTip.visible: hovered
        ToolTip.text: "hello world"
    }
}
```

The text colour works, but the background doesn't.

[image]

Why does it not show the blue background rectangle?

I am using Qt6 with PySide6.

*edit:

I have tried using `TextMetrics` to give the background a width and height. Is this the idiomatic way to do it? It feels like I shouldn't need text metrics. This also leaves the Label uncentered in the background, which looks bad.

```
import QtQuick.Templates 2.0 as T
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

T.ToolTip {
    id: ctrl
    contentItem: Label {
        color: "red"
        text: ctrl.text
    }
    background: Rectangle {
        id: bg
        color: "yellow"
        width: tmet.width + 5
        height: tmet.height + 5
    }
    TextMetrics {
        id: tmet
        font: ctrl.font
        text: ctrl.text
    }
}
```

Comment: Try giving an `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` to your background object.

Comment: @JarMan See my edit.  implicitWidth and implicitHeight did not work, but width and height did. But it still looks bad, and I doubt this is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Everytime I need to create custom controls I'll look into the QtQuick Basic style. On my machine I can find it here `Qt/6.4.0/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Basic/ToolTip.qml`

> Templates are non-visual implementations of controls' logic and
> behavior.

You need to set a size on the `ToolTip`. Look how they are setting the `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` of the `ToolTip`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls.impl
import QtQuick.Templates as T

T.ToolTip {
    id: control

    x: parent ? (parent.width - implicitWidth) / 2 : 0
    y: -implicitHeight - 3

    implicitWidth: Math.max(implicitBackgroundWidth + leftInset + rightInset,
                            contentWidth + leftPadding + rightPadding)
    implicitHeight: Math.max(implicitBackgroundHeight + topInset + bottomInset,
                             contentHeight + topPadding + bottomPadding)

    margins: 6
    padding: 6

    closePolicy: T.Popup.CloseOnEscape | T.Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent | T.Popup.CloseOnReleaseOutsideParent

    contentItem: Text {
        text: control.text
        font: control.font
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
        color: control.palette.toolTipText
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        border.color: control.palette.dark
        color: control.palette.toolTipBase
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a look at the documentation and checked `qtquickcontrols2/src/imports/controls/ToolTip.qml` source code and, it does seem that the correct setting of implicitWidth / implicitHeight is key.

Answer (score 0):

To set the toolTip text color, it is not necessary to define a custom contentItem `Label` component. You can change the tooltip color by setting `palette.toolTipText`.

I can see your use case is to try to apply a custom `ToolTip` style so that all your components will inherit.

[EDIT: Change the direction of my answer to a custom Button instead of changing the default ToolTip style]

Alternatively, consider implementing custom components that have a custom `ToolTip` style. e.g. instead of `Button`, consider having `MyButton`. This way, we leave the default `Button` with the default style.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    MyButton {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        id: button
        text: "Click me"
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Clicked")
        }
        ToolTip.visible: hovered
        ToolTip.text: "hello world"
    }
}

// MyButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Button {
    ToolTip {
        visible: parent.hovered
        text: parent.ToolTip.text
        palette.toolTipText: "red"
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "lightsteelblue"
            border.color: "yellow"
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACRXicdZG7bsMwDEV3fYXgqV2U3WMzdSjQFP4BWSZsIbTo0nQeKPzvlR9VnATlJImX5OWRbzti0Qc5DN4dlb+7mj0FYcJefdoa9I/SMT6ub4MIhfU6hQ2uIe6NgyDA7yHXneV4TgJf5bqcq9KTwEVyne0xztEtZClBYX6DWHKbMIWj0BOCQapfslWTvSbJmE4FERa+Myff+xIh1w2dgKF6EqweGkAkfSbGarExqlGp3S6tar5bfEDzL6k7OOugzSLJ00LIPFpbLK3Jrc+k6CyCCBhZksWyQ+xxQ1had6yZhhAZfoETG2qEJ5pIHAvR1430AoAlDptvmPsQV8DmT3qdOJ2zB+IR1i9/baue)

Comment: OP asked about "Creating a custom style" in this case the name of the file needs to match the control. If on the other hand, he wants to customize a control then you are right, the name of the custom control should differ or use proper namespaces as shown in the link OP shared.

Comment: Thanks @iam_peter. I will reread that section.